# Transfer data form database to database php

Tags: php, sql

I have this code that is working great!, but instead echo I need to pass the data that is suppose to echo from one database to another, I tested the next code in the phpadmin and do the work of copying the data without duplicity from one database to another and delete from barcode what I add in voters, but I don't know where I can put it inside the php code.

**Insert IGNORE into voters
Select * from barcode where id = the id from database;
DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)**

Both database have the same columns: id, credentials, password, firstname, lastname

````
    include 'includes/conn.php';
    include 'includes/scripts.php'; 


    if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
        $sca=trim($_POST['no'],"");     
        $flag=0;
        $credentials="";
        $password="";
        $firstname="";
        $lastname="";
        $new2 ="SELECT * FROM `barcode`";
        $res2=mysqli_query($conn, $new2);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
            //echo $row['number'].'<br>';
        // if($row['number']){
                    if($row['credentials'] == $sca){
                        $flag=1;
                        $credentials=$row['credentials'];
                        $password=$row['password'];
                        $firstname=$row['firstname'];
                        $lastname=$row['lastname'];
                    }
            
    }if ($flag==1) {
            echo

                  '<br><b>Registro:</b>'.' '.$credentials.
                  '<br><b>Contraseña:</b>'.' '.$password.
                  '<br><b>Nombre:</b>'.' '.$firstname.
                  '<br><b>Apellidos:</b>'.' '.$lastname.
                  
                  "</div></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3'></div><div class='col-sm-6'>" ;
                         return;

   }
   else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center mt-3'>Product Not Found</div></div>";    
                return;
            }
    
    }

mysqli_close($conn);
 
?>```
````

Comment: once you retrieve all data from 1st database then you need to close connection with 1st database and create connection for 2nd database insert data you retried from 1st database into 2nd database then close the connection of 2nd database. Now if you want to delete from 1st database you can again open connection for 1st database and delete records.

Comment: @AqibJaved You can have multiple connections open to different databases